# How to display simple HTML in a Silverlight textblock?

Tags: html, silverlight, textblock

I've got a source of data that has HTML tags in it (B, I, A) and need to display this in a Silverlight ListBox.

Searching around it seems to be an issue but most of the posts are old and have to do with Silverlight 1 it seems.

What is currently the best way to display simple HTML with Silverlight, if nothing else, just the B, I and A tags for bold, italic and hyperlinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no native support in Silverlight 2.0. However, someone has gone and created a `HtmlTextBlock` control which should be suitable for your purposes. Check out the author's [block post](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2008/03/17/continuing-support-for-simple-html-display-in-silverlight-htmltextblock-sample-updated-for-silverlight-2-beta-1.aspx) on the subject. There's also a demo page [here](http://dlaa.me/Samples/SilverlightHtmlTextBlock/).

Comment: Seems like the server hosting the blog is down at the moment. You can still download the source from http://delay.members.winisp.net/SilverlightHtmlTextBlock/SilverlightHtmlTextBlock.zip. Note that it was written for the Silverlight 2.0 beta, so it may need some minor modifications to work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it just in XAML:

```
<TextBlock>
    Text:&#160;<Italic>italic</Italic>&#160;and&#160;<Bold>bold</Bold>
</TextBlock>
```

the &#160 is an antity for space. The result is:

Text: *italic* and **bold**

Answer (score -1):

This comment system is wacky. I added 2 comments last night. After adding the second one, I could still only see the first one. This morning, after clearing browser cookies, I only see my second one. Wierd.

Anyway, I had a problem with the control where I had its Html property bound, and it was appending html every time the property changed. I fixed it by adding the following to the top of the `ParseAndSetText()` method:

```
this.SelectAll();            
this.Selection.Text = "";
```

I also had a problem where an exception was being thrown when the DOM parsing routine failed, and I fixed it by changing:

```
Xaml = null;
```

with

```
this.SelectAll();            
this.Selection.Text = "";
```