# HTML snippets in silverlight

Tags: html, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display simple HTML in a Silverlight textblock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748050/how-to-display-simple-html-in-a-silverlight-textblock)

I've got a silverlight 4.0 app running with C# & a SQL Server back end.

The Sql Server DB is populated via another process that includes saving html content (primarily links & p tags, but occasionally other, more complicated HTML).

I've got a telerik license, but their RadHtmlPlaceholder sits on top of everything, and part of this content is a lightbox-style popup that displays youtube videos & flickr images, so I can't go that route.

I'm using a list box template to display a list of 20 tweets, for example. Inside many tweets, HTML content has been saved to my db. I want to display this content & render the HTML (so instead of `<a href="www.mysite.com">link</a>`, it displays as [link](http://link/)). My bindings currently are set up as:

```
<TextBlock Padding="10,0,10,0" LineHeight="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Span FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#0A5582"><Run Text="{Binding PostTitle}" />:</Span>
    <Run Text="{Binding PostContent}" />
</TextBlock>
```

I'm baffled that I can't do this natively. What are my options?

Comment: take a look here: [How to display simple HTML in a Silverlight textblock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748050/how-to-display-simple-html-in-a-silverlight-textblock)

Comment: FYI for others - this link above is an "updated" version of the link I posted below. I added an updated link in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the HTMLTextBlock defined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx)

Updated version [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2008/03/17/continuing-support-for-simple-html-display-in-silverlight-htmltextblock-sample-updated-for-silverlight-2-beta-1.aspx)